# Dropping columns when using tabout

Tags: stata

I use `tabout` to produce output tables in Stata 14. I want to drop the last two columns of my table. The handbook states that this can be done using the `dropc()` option.

This is my code:

```
tabout var_one var_two if year==2014 using table1.xlsx, ///
cells(freq col) format(0 2p) clab(N %) dropc(5 6) ptotal(none) replace
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

> option dropc() not allowed

The code works fine if I remove the `dropc()` option. There isn't anything in the handbook that suggests why this is happening and a google search has turned up nothing.

Comment: Your code is not enough for us to replicate your problem. We need example data. Please read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using version 2 of the *community-contributed* command `tabout`, which is available on SSC.

The aforementioned error arises because option `dropc()` only works in version 3 beta.

You need to manually install this newer version by downloading the following file from the author's website into your `adopath` ([click here](http://tabout.net.au/downloads/tabout_user_guide.pdf#section.1.3) for more information):

```
http://tabout.net.au/downloads/main_version/tabout.txt
```

You should also rename the extension to `tabout.ado`. Note that this is the file for Stata 14 and later.

Once installed, the `dropc()` option will work:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tabout mpg price if foreign == 1 using table1.txt, ///
cells(freq col) format(0 2p) dropc(5 6) clab(N %) ptotal(none) replace
```